# resize images with height flexbox

Tags: image, css, flexbox

I have a column with images. The column has a limited height and I want that all the images fit in the column vertically. Is this possible? I'm trying it with flexbox, but didn't succeed yet.

```css
.zoom__images {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom__images">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/42/d4/66/42d466fd73a3b284f49d3020c27cf80e--aloes-martin-omalley.jpg" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/42/d4/66/42d466fd73a3b284f49d3020c27cf80e--aloes-martin-omalley.jpg" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/42/d4/66/42d466fd73a3b284f49d3020c27cf80e--aloes-martin-omalley.jpg" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/42/d4/66/42d466fd73a3b284f49d3020c27cf80e--aloes-martin-omalley.jpg" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
</div>
```

Best wishes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This will work if you want to take equal size for your images

For flex-items to shrink less than their size you need to set `flex-basis: 0;` and `min-height: 0`. Default values of `min-height: auto` and `flex-basis: auto;` can prevent flex-items from shrinking less than their size. `flex-grow: 1` makes items grow to take equal values. But `img` as flex-items don't resize to preserve aspect ratio, so we'll have to wrap them. Demo:

```css
.zoom__images {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.zoom__images > * {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.zoom__images img {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom__images">
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/250x175/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/a00/fff"></div>
  <div><img src="https://placehold.it/400x600/a00/fff"></div>
</div>
```

You can also add `overflow: hidden` for `.zoom__images > *` for images not overflowing `.zoom__images`. This won't make it look as in other browsers but look will be much better.

Comment: That looks great, nice one Vadim!

Comment: Looks good alright, although IE11 still refuses to show them as requested. Not to mention Edge, which has no clue!!

Comment: Almost there, but IE11 doe not see `height: 300px` and shows images at full size. Edge, FF, Chrome, Vivaldi (chrome base) are ok. (removed my answer btw)

Comment: @RenevanderLende Added workaround for IE, at least this will make it look better than now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS calc() method. calc(100/Number of images in container) will resize your images' height to share 100% of your container height, which will be divided evenly among all images.

```css
.zoom__images {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  height: calc(100%/4);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoom__images">
        <img src="https://mrose.org/cc/png-test.png" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
        <img src="https://mrose.org/cc/png-test.png" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
        <img src="https://mrose.org/cc/png-test.png" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
        <img src="https://mrose.org/cc/png-test.png" class="" alt="Simple Picture">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about doing that, but sometimes there are less or more images. So it should be more flexible.

Comment: I will look into it further